# AngularJS drag & drop editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJS pls guide me from the core level.

My requirement is to drag & drop items(source) into create dynamic tree structure (target). Pls find the attached screenshot.

In the source i have list of items which need to be dragged to form a dynamic tree structure in which all the nodes in the tree should be editable.

Ex 1: creation/edit of Tree structure

Step1) An item is selected from source and dragged to target

Step2) In the target side **Product catalog** will be created with default name & timestamp. Under Product catalog **product** will be created. Under Product **items** will be created. Finally selected item will be dropped under items as shown in the screenshot. There can be multiple items added under this category.

FYI: If the selected item is dropped at Product level, implicitly another product structure will be created under same product catalog.

Pls let me know the approach to take it forward.

Thanks

vij

Answer (score 1):

Use **HTML5 Content Editable attribute** to edit the page contents on the go and make sure to have a control of it (ex: Admin mode)

Use control flags in your angular controller to allow the user to edit the contents.

For drag and drop, you have to use 3rd party plugins and there are tons open source plugins available.

To make the contents editable,

```
<p contenteditable="true">You can edit me!</p>
```

For Angular's sake,

```
<p contenteditable="isAdminMode">You can edit me!</p>
```

Set, `$scope.isAdminMode = true || false` based on a situation.

Comment: Thanks vinay for the response.  In my case using REST service i will be getting the JSON structure i need to hide few fields in UI and remaining fields should be editable. could u pls suggest with an example.

Comment: Use ng-if or ng-show to remove/hide a portion in your view.

Comment: Hi Vinay, While dropping a element into tree structure i need to select appropriate node where the value should be appended. Pls suggest the possible way to take it forward.

Comment: Every node will have an index value when you loop through a collection in ng-repeat.

Comment: Just use array.splice(index, 1) to remove the particular element in your tree. Make sure to reflect the splice operation in database too.

Comment: Can you pls edit the below code. This is showstopper to me                   http://plnkr.co/edit/jexHopqfkmZWlGgldNoy?p=preview

Comment: I gave you a note. Try yourself.

Comment: to insert the dragged item into a specific tree node, In the "$scope.onDropComplete" method how i can i get specific index value of the tree node while dragging ? pls suggest.

Comment: $index will have the numbered index of an instance.

Comment: Vinay need yur help pls..... Within "$scope.onDropComplete" method  the statement "$index.treemap.children" is returning the message "undefined". How can i write event generator which prints index value of the treenode while dropping the value in the tree.

Comment: Couple of things.. $index is just an index of array. If you want to access a node you should pass the index value to the function where you want to perform something with the node.

Comment: <div>
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.dragableNode}} <---> <button ng-click="items.splice(index, 1)">Remove</button></li>
 </ul>
</div>

Comment: Try the above snippet

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed. Actually we created default tree structure in which we had put a option to create node at every child and parent along with delete option.